# Unable to disable extern indentation with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm not sure if this is a limitation or bug with clang-format (built from source, `clang-format version 12.0.0 (git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git d4ce062340064c3f73b8f6136c7350a5abe83cac)`), but I am unable to disable indentation after `extern "C" {`.

My current `.clang-format`:

```
Language: Cpp
Standard: Latest

UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 4
AccessModifierOffset: -2
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
ColumnLimit: 80
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman

FixNamespaceComments: true
SortIncludes: true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
IncludeBlocks: Regroup

IndentPPDirectives: AfterHash
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentExternBlock: NoIndent
NamespaceIndentation: All

AlignTrailingComments: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: true
AlignConsecutiveMacros: true
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak

AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes

BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 500 # basically always break

# Note: must have my custom build (https://github.com/jasperswallen/llvm-project/tree/pointeralignment-right) to properly enable these options
BreakBeforeConceptDeclarations: true
PointerAlignment: Right
```

This example file is the "formatted" result:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    void example(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

but I want something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

void example(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

It seems like `IndentExternBlock: NoIndent` should be the correct option to force this, but it's still indenting even with that set.

Is it possible that `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman` is overriding this setting? I assumed that `IndentExternBlock` would override braces unless set to `AfterExternBlock`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [bug 37272](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37272), but there is just a little chance that it will be fixed because this option (`IndentExternBlock`) was forced by [expand preset function](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/lib/Format/Format.cpp#L805). Please review the following [problematic commit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/6ef45b0426a8c7b9764e102fb1a49561a3a2c118).

We can see that llvm developers broke config inheritance and nobody cares about a year. It means that we have to fix config inheritance in a way that won't depend on llvm developers. Please review the following solution:

`scripts/clang/config-format/config-source.yml`

```yaml
Language: Cpp
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
```

`scripts/clang/config-format/config-updates.yml`

```yaml
BraceWrapping:
  AfterExternBlock: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
IndentExternBlock: false
```

`scripts/clang/config-format/update.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

DIR=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
cd "$DIR"

SOURCE="config-source.yml"
UPDATES="config-updates.yml"
DESTINATION="../../../.clang-format"

echo "# This file has been auto generated, please don't edit directly." \
  > "$DESTINATION"

SOURCE_STYLE=$(yq -cs ".[0]" < "$SOURCE")

clang-format -style="$SOURCE_STYLE" --dump-config | \
  yq -sy ".[0] * .[1]" - "$UPDATES" >> "$DESTINATION"
```

Please install [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). After running `./scripts/clang/config-format/update.sh` you will receive proper `.clang-config` for your requirements.